# Setting shipping carrier and method in Magento order

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

I'm trying to batch update orders to create a shipment/tracking number for every order. My scrips is working great -- it's marking them as shipped, assigning a tracking number, etc. However, I cannot figure out how to assign the new shipments carrier name, or where I even find it! For example, if they shipped with UPS, I need to set UPS as the carrier. I have full access to the order, via the order id.

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order_id);

$shipment->register();
$order->setIsInProcess(true);

$tracking = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_track')
    ->setCarrierCode(NEED CARRIER HERE)
    ->setTitle($order->getShippingDescription())
    ->setNumber($tracking_number);

$shipment->addTrack($tracking);

$transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
    ->addObject($shipment)
    ->addObject($shipment->getOrder())
    ->save();

$shipment->sendEmail(true);
```

Can anybody spot where I am going wrong? Or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Take a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887198/programmatically-send-shipping-tracking-mail